# How to get blunt ends with tkz-euclide with \tkzDrawSegment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

How do I get blunt ends (straight, not rounded) using \tkzDrawSegment in tkz-euclide. The default appears to be rounded ends. I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Do I have to invoke a blunt arrowhead?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}   
       \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
       \tkzDefPoint(1,1){B}
       \tkzDrawSegment[line width=8,black](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ude `Tikz`options

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}   
         \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
         \tkzDefPoint(1,1){B}
         \tkzDrawSegment[line width=8,black,line cap= rect](A,B)
  \end{tikzpicture} 

  \end{document}
```

[image]

You also modify the tkz-euclide.cfg and you modify

```
\tikzset{%
line style/.style = {%
    line width = \tkz@euc@linewidth,
    color      = \tkz@euc@linecolor,
    style      = \tkz@euc@linestyle,
    add        = {\tkz@euc@lineleft} and    {\tkz@euc@lineright},
    line cap   = round
    }
}
```

Possible is to modify `line style/.style`. The choice of the method depends if you want a modification local or global for your document or global for all your documents.

Comment: Didn't know about the line cap, thanks.